# Is there a step by step guide to adding dimensions to a floorplan?

Tags: architecture

I'm learning AutoCAD and decided to make a floorplan as my first project. I know how to insert dimensions in AutoCAD but I don't know where to actually put them. E.g. in this image do I put the distance between the outeredge of the wall and the door or the inner edge of the wall and the door? Can I put the written dimensions on the inside of the building instead of the outside? These questions might not be very clear but basically what I'm asking is: is there a step by step guide for putting dimensions in a floor plan. I've looked at some images of floorplans and they're really not helping me much

[image: there is z-ish shaped area (it goes right -> up 5' -> right again) with a door that swings outward into the corner]

Comment: https://shop.bsigroup.com/ProductDetail/?pid=000000000001152913 May have the information you’re looking for, albeit behind a paywall... Fingers crossed one of the others here can help you more frugally!

Comment: It may vary from country to county &/or from profession to profession - engineering & architecture

Answer (score 1):

From my drafting classes civil drawings were the most difficult because the rules were less strict. I preferred machine drawings where everything had to be precise. As for some general rules, I strongly recommend consistency, if you give wall / room dimensions using inside distances, keep with that. Wall thickness can be listed in a note with a leader to specific walls or like this "Interior walls 4" thick, exterior 6" thick".

Overall dimensions of the whole house are external but room, door, window and most locating distances are inside unless they make more sense to be outside. Like if you want to ensure the front door is located centered on the front of the house then giving a distance from an interior wall of a room that's not centered will not ensure the door is where you want it but you may want to include those internal dimensions even though they are redundant.